# iTerm2 tabs don't start different terminal session

Tags: iterm2

I've installed iTerm2 on all of my computers (OS X). On each of them, when I hit <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>t</kbd>, a new tab opens and I get a new session... except for one of them. On this one, when I hit <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>t</kbd>, a new tab opens, but it's the same session. Anything I do in one tab is reflected in all of the tabs.

I've read through the preferences a few times and haven't seen anything that would control this. Googled it too.

Anyone know what's up here?

**EDIT 1**

To clarify:

When I first start (only 1 tab) and do an `ls` I will see the directory structure in the window. When I launch a new tab (tab 2), both tabs will be a clean terminal session. When I do `nslookup google.com` I will see the nslookup output in both tabs. When I launch a new tab (tab 3), all tabs will be a clean terminal session. When I do `curl google.com` I will see the the curl output in all three tabs. When I close tab 3, the remaining two tabs show the nslookup output. When I close tab 2 I am back to the original ls output.

In the above scenario up to tab 2, if I drag tab 2 to it's own window, tab 2 correctly has the nslookup output and tab 1 correctly has the ls output.

If I don't use <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>t</kbd> and instead create new windows with <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>n</kbd> this issue doesn't occur.

Comment: So I am understanding correctly; whatever you type or is output by a command (std in, std out, std err) is also shown in all the other tabs? If you detached (drag) the tab to have it hosted in its own window, all input and output is shown in both windows? If you Cmd-N for a new window, the same results? or just tabs/Cmd-T is doing this?

Comment: Addressed your questions by editing my original post.

Comment: Ok, really strange, ... almost a feature :-)  Assuming iTerm2 2.11, OS-X 10.10.x.. In the default profile that is being used are you using the 'Login shell' or a custom shell/command/script (via the General/Command Pref. section)?

Comment: It's set to login shell

Answer (score 0):

Menu item:
 `Shell / Broadcast Input` is *not* set to "Send Input to Current Session Only"

[image]