# How to create a new content/bash when creating a new tab in iTerm2

Tags: shell, iterm2

I installed the iTerm with Build 3.0.15.
However, iTerm has not create a new content/bash for me when I create a new tab (ctrl+t).
Thus, these two tabs will work in the same action.

ex. 
In tab1, I type "pwd" , tab2 will also show "pwd".
It means these two tabs are the same content/bash or even the same process.

But this situation will not happen when I create a new window(ctrl+n).
I do all the steps through the https://iterm2.com/why_no_content.html , but it still not work.

[my iTerm2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6SFrM.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32027829/iterm2-tabs-dont-start-different-terminal-session/32029022#32029022

Comment: Thank you, but it's already set to Send Input to Current Session Only.